# clarification over the negation for the definition of topological embedding

Tags: general-topology

For the following question:

Let $\text{~}$ be the smallest relation on $\mathbb{R}$ defined by $x\text{~}y$ if $x$ and $y$ are integers.  Then the quotient space $\mathbb{R}/\text{~}$ is not embeddable in $\mathbb{R}^2$

I would like to know how to formulate in mathematical language what it means for one space $X$ to not be embeddable in $Y$.  I know that the definition of embedding from one space to another in terms of homeomorphism and subspace topology are as follows:

**Definition:** Let $(X,\mathcal{T})$ and $(Y,\mathcal{U})$ be topological spaces.  If $(A,\mathcal{U}_A)$ is a subspace of $(Y,\mathcal{U})$ and $f:(X,\mathcal{T})\rightarrow (A,\mathcal{U}_A)$ is a homeomorphism, then $X$ is said to be embedded in $Y$  and $f$ is called an embedding of $X$ in $Y$.

and also, according to the following proposition on embedding (from K.D.Joshi's Introduction to General Topology Text)

**Proposition:**  A function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is an embedding iff it is continuous and one-to-one and for every open set $V$ in $X$, there existss an open subset $A$ of $Y$ such that $f(V)=A\cap Y$

So for a space $X$ to not be embeddable into another space $Y$, does it involve a non exsistence of a homeomorphic mapping $f$ from $X$ to $f(X)$ but also, $f(V)\neq A\cap Y$, for some $V \subset X$ and some $A \subset Y$

Thank you in advance

Comment: The Proposition is a simple reformulation of the Definition. So what is your question?

Comment: It just means that no map $X\to Y$ is an embedding.

Comment: @PaulFrost, i am trying to understand how to express precisely what it means for one space to not be embeddable into another.  The way the definition seems to be a bit complicated involving many quantifiers.

Comment: For some (any) property P, a space Y is called hereditarily P if every subspace of Y (including Y itself) has property P.  A property P is called a topological property if X' has property P whenever X' is the homeomorphic image of a space X that has property P.... Being not-first-countable is a topological property. And $\Bbb R^2$ is hereditarily first-countable.

Comment: An exception to the def'n of hereditarily P is made when P is the property of being disconnected. A space X is hereditarily disconnected if X is disconnected and every subpace of X with at least 2 members is disconnected.

Answer (score 1):

$X$ is embeddable in $Y$ iff $X$ is homeomorphic to a subspace of $Y$.

So its negation can be formulated as "no subspace of $Y$ is homeomorphic to $X$".

Which in this case is easy to see, as (e.g.) all subspaces of $\Bbb R^2$ are first-countable while $\Bbb R{/}\text{~}$ is not first-countable.

Comment: thank you for your response.  When you say no subspace of $Y$ is homeomorphic to $X$, does it mean the following:  if we assign a topology $T$ to $Y$, and for any $A\subset Y$, with  $T_A = A\cap O$ for some open set $O \in T$, $f(T_A)$ is not homeomorphic to $X$.

Comment: No, @SethMai we don't assign a topology to $Y$, it already *has* a topology $\mathcal{T}_Y$, and then for all $A \subseteq Y$, there is no homeomorphism between $X$ (in its pregiven topology) and $A$ in the subspace topology $\{A \cap O: O \in \mathcal{T}_Y\}$. You statement makes no sense at all.

Comment: I was trying understand and formulate how embedding can fail..  After looking at the proposition,  There seems to be more than one conditions that could make one space not be embedded in another.  I am glad you can clarify it for me.  Thank you again.